# Formating an object array toString() output in Java

Tags: java, formatting, output

I have trouble aligning the output of an array[] of Objects when calling the `.toString` method.

```
System.out.println(books.toString());
```

and formatted my `.toString()` to get the alignment of the object variables like this

```
public static String header(){
    return "%1$-25s %2$-20s %3$-20s %4$-1s";
}
    
@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.format(header(), title, author, copies, "\n");
}
```

Bellow is the result I get and I would like to remove the first character of each row and have the book names ,in this case, lined up

```
[To Kill a Mockingbird     Harper Lee           30                   
, 1984                      George Orwell        3                    
, The Lord of the Rings     J.R.R. Tolkien       78                   
, The Book Thief            Markus Zusak         32                   
, The Grapes of Wrath       John Steinbeck       67                   
]
```

like this

```
To Kill a Mockingbird     Harper Lee           30                   
1984                      George Orwell        3                    
The Lord of the Rings     J.R.R. Tolkien       78                   
The Book Thief            Markus Zusak         32                   
The Grapes of Wrath       John Steinbeck       67
```

Is it possible to do this with the .toString() or would I necesarily have to go with a loop for every Object to output my data?

Comment: You have to write your own print loop if you don't want the `[ , ]` characters in the output. Or use `Stream` with `joining()`.

Comment: I wonder that `books.toString()` is even giving that output (`books` being an array)

Comment: @user15358848 he's added  a new line in `Book.toString()` each book entry toString is yielding new line.  :p

Comment: @onkar that is not the point. Arrays do not implement the `toString()` method (OP posted `books.toString()`), so the version of `Object` is used, which does not output the content of the array (e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/409784/15358848)

Answer (score 0):

From your code I observe that you override toString() method on object class so in this case you should use a for loop for print every object or you can create a new method. The new method must be has a loop for print all object

```
public string printAll(Book[] books){
//then for/while loop to iterate every element//
//then print
}
```

I think this will work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the `books`, which is an array of `Book`, the way you want it, you can do this.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(books).map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `books` seems to be `List` or another collection, not an array of books `Book[]`, if it prints the mentioned output.

Thus, if books is an iterable collection, its method [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) may be used instead of loop:

```java
books.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or, if `books` need to be converted into a single String, `Collectors.joining` should be used as Andreas mentioned in the comment:

```java
String toPrint = books.stream().map(Book::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. 
It worked wonders and was very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static method in Book class:

```
public static void prettyPrintBooks(Book[] books) {
  //print header

  for(Book b : books){
     //print each book row
  }

}
```

You can call this method like: `Book.prettyPrintBooks(books);`